# Python XML Parse Hang?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

EDIT:

I have a script that parses a sitemap xml and stores the first pass in an array. I then have it set so that it refreshes, parses and stores a desired xml tag into another array to check for any differences. This second array is constantly updated every 3 seconds on the xmls refresh. However, it seems to get hung up and I am wondering what the problem is.

```
import urllib,time
from time import gmtime, strftime
from xml.dom import minidom
url='http://kutoa.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=1&to=999999999'
def main():
    primList=[]
    secList=[]
    xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml)
    loc_values = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('loc')
    for loc_val in loc_values:
        item=(loc_val.firstChild.nodeValue)
        primList.append(item)
    for i in primList:
        secList.append(item)
    while len(secList)==len(primList):
        print str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))+' :: '+str(len(secList)) +' items indexed...'
        print 'destruct list'
        secList=[]
        print 'empty list/reading url'
        xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        print 'url read/parsing'
        xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml)
        print 'parsed going for tags'
            loc_values = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('loc')
        print 'adding tags'
        for loc_val in loc_values:
            item=(loc_val.firstChild.nodeValue)
            secList.append(item)
        print 'tags added to list'
        time.sleep(3)
        print 'sleep for 3\n'
    if len(primList)>len(secList):
            print 'items removed'
            main()
    elif len(secList)>len(primList):
            print 'items added'
            main()
main()
```

With print statements for troubleshooting I see that it gets hung up on opening the url. Here is some recent output:

```
2015-12-26 18:30:21 :: 7 items indexed...
destruct list
empty list/reading url
url read/parsing
parsed going for tags
adding tags
tags added to list
sleep for 3

2015-12-26 18:30:24 :: 7 items indexed...
destruct list
empty list/reading url
url read/parsing
parsed going for tags
adding tags
tags added to list
sleep for 3

2015-12-26 18:30:27 :: 7 items indexed...
destruct list
empty list/reading url
```

and then nothing more will output and my program will just hang, un-terminated under the last parse output. Is this network related? Any thoughts/remedies would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add more output so that you can tell which line is hanging.

Comment: Also, is this an external web-site?  If so, it may have some logic to avoid being overloaded by repeated requests like this.  Try only polling every minute.

Comment: @MartinBonner thank you for the reply. By adding some basic print statements for troubleshooting I see that it's getting stuck here:   xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

Comment: The call to `urlopen` seems the most likely to hang, so you might want to call `socket.setdefaulttimeout` with a timeout value and then optionally catch the `socket.timeout` exception.

Comment: Thank you @cr3. How would I go about implementing this? Also, would changing my polling time in the sleep method render a difference?

Comment: I'll provide more details as an answer, one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your function, before calling `urlopen`, you might want to set the socket timeout to prevent the call from potentially hanging forever. This snippet sets the timeout to 3 seconds for consistency with your sleep value:

```
import socket

def main():
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
    ...
```

Then, wrap your call to `urlopen` to catch the `socket.timeout` exception. This snippet just prints a string and continues your loop:

```
try:
    xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
except socket.timeout as e:
    print 'timeout reading url: %s' % e
    continue
print 'url read/parsing'
...
```

I haven't tested this so let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had much experience with these but with some exception handling like this I'm able to continue on. I implemented a try on the first parse for the first array and within the while loop with an IOError exception.

Comment: Since you don't have much experience with handling exceptions, I made a smell edit in my second snippet to assign the exception to variable `e` and then include that variable in the printed string. You might find it useful when troubleshooting problems like this.